# .MSG File Metadata Extraction - Sender SMTP Email

Tags: c#, email, exchangewebservices, office-interop, aspose

Our organization is currently in the process of extracting a processing old .MSG files that have been stored by current and possibly former employees. As part of this process we are trying to extract the Sender SMTP email address from these old emails. However since most of these were/are internal users, the msg file has the Sender Address stored as an exchange address. We have tried the following to with no luck:

**

### MsgReader.Outlook.Storage.Message

**

```
var senderAddress = string.Empty;
using (var msg = new Storage.Message(emailFilePath))
{
    senderAddress = msg.Sender.Email;
}
```

**

### Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem

**

```
var senderEmailAddress = this.SafeExtractEmailAddress(mail.Sender, mail.SenderEmailAddress);


private string SafeExtractEmailAddress(AddressEntry addressEntry, string currentEmail)
{
    var userEmailAddress = string.Empty;

    if (addressEntry != null &&
        (addressEntry.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeUserAddressEntry
            || addressEntry.AddressEntryUserType == OlAddressEntryUserType.olExchangeRemoteUserAddressEntry))
    {
        userEmailAddress = addressEntry.GetExchangeUser()?.PrimarySmtpAddress;
    }

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(userEmailAddress))
    {
        var recipient = this.outlookApplication.Session.CreateRecipient(currentEmail);
        var exchangeUser = recipient?.AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser();

        userEmailAddress = exchangeUser?.PrimarySmtpAddress ?? currentEmail;

        recipient.SafeRelease();
        exchangeUser.SafeRelease();
    }

    return userEmailAddress.ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

**

### Aspose.Email.Mapi.MapiMessage

**

```
public string ExtractSender(MapiMessage msg)
{
    if (msg == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(msg));
    }
    var senderEmailAddress = msg.SenderEmailAddress;
    ExchangeService exchangeService = this.exchangeServiceFactory.BuildService();

    // Create the ResolveNamesType and set the unresolved entry.

    if (msg.SenderAddressType == "EX")
    { 
        var resolutionCollection = exchangeService.ResolveName(msg.SenderEmailAddress, ResolveNameSearchLocation.ContactsThenDirectory, true);
        var nameResolutions = resolutionCollection.ToList();
        if (nameResolutions.Count > 0)
        {
            var nameResolution = nameResolutions.ElementAt(0);
            senderEmailAddress = nameResolution.Mailbox.Address;
        }
    }

    return senderEmailAddress;
}
```

What other options do I have to obtain this data?

Comment: Take a look at the MSG file with OutlokSpy (click OpenIMsgOnIStg button) - chances are ptagSenderSmtpAddress property will be present.

Comment: This may be a credential issue.  The email address is stored in the User Account c:\Users (in XP it was Document and Settings).

Comment: @jdweng I'm not sure how that will resolve our issue of extracting smtp email addresses from historic .msg email files. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 0):

While using Aspose.Email.Mapi.MapiMessage, the object of this class has following properties returning Sender information:

- msg.SenderEmailAddress
- msg.SenderSmtpAddress

Both properties get or set the message sender's e-mail address.

You may use the following code snippet to load and read MSG information:

```
// Create an instance of MapiMessage from file
MapiMessage msg = MapiMessage.FromFile(dataDir + @"message.msg");

// Get subject
Console.WriteLine("Subject:" + msg.Subject);

// Get from address
Console.WriteLine("Sender:" + msg.SenderEmailAddress);
Console.WriteLine("Sender SMTP:" + msg.SenderSmtpAddress);

// Get body
Console.WriteLine("Body" + msg.Body);

// Get recipients information
Console.WriteLine("Recipient: " + msg.Recipients);

// Get attachments
foreach (MapiAttachment att in msg.Attachments)
{
    Console.Write("Attachment Name: " + att.FileName);
    Console.Write("Attachment Display Name: " + att.DisplayName);
}
```

Note: I am working as Support developer/ Evangelist at Aspose.

Comment: The sender smtp came out null. I believe some of these messages may have been save from the user's sent mail folder. Maybe this is the reason we cannot get the sender smtp using Aspose?

Comment: In that case, you may get folder information as well, like as:// get the folders and messages information
                FolderInfo folderInfo = pst.RootFolder;
                FolderInfoCollection folders = folderInfo.GetSubFolders();
                foreach (FolderInfo myfolderInfo in folders)
                {
Console.WriteLine("Folder: " + folderInfo.DisplayName);
                }

Comment: We only have .MSG files to extract information from. These are emails that have been stored by different employees over the past couple of years.

Comment: You may check the type of sender address by reading "msg.SenderAddressType" which shows message sender's email address type. In case SenderAddressType is EX, the email address is not saved but you may find a long string against "msg.SenderEmailAddress".

Comment: We're currently doing that and using the exchange address to query ews to get the smtp address. We do not prefer this for two reasons.
1. Its time consuming.
2. Does not work out for retired employees.

Comment: You may share sample MSG file, so that we could investigate in detail.